Polynomial time algorithm for 3SAT
I followed from this question.
I am following the book, Theory of Computational Complexity, 2nd Edition Ding-Zhu Du, Ker-I Ko.
I am copying following text from the book,
Recently an algorithm was found that solves the isomorphism problem between $\text{GI}$ graphs in time $2^{O(\log^c(n))}$ for permanent certain $1 < c.$
Reminder:

the language $\text{GI} = \{\langle _1, _2 \rangle∶ _1 \text{ is isomorphic to } _2\}$
the language $\text{GNI} = \{\langle _1, _2 \rangle∶ _1 \text{ is NOT isomorphic to } _2\}$

As for, the graphs in the above context are not directed. Assume in addition that we know that this is the optimal complexity of the problem (i.e., best algorithm).
My question is: how to prove or refute that there exists a polynomial time algorithm for $\text{3SAT}$?
My progress:
GI is in NP. Since, Given $(G_1, G_2)$ along with the bijection $φ$ as a certificate to the poly time deterministic verifier
$M$. It can easily verify whether G1 and G2 are isomorphic or not.GNI is the complement of GI. Thus, $\text{GNI} ∈ \text{co-NP}$.
From here, how to proceed to show that there exists or not a polynomial time algorithm for $\text{3SAT}$? Anybody help me to complete the proof.

Perhaps better asked at the theoretical computer science stackexchange.

If the given algorithm for GI is optimal, then P$\not=$NP. Since 3SAT is NP-complete, it follows that 3SAT is not solvable in polynomial time. Is this what you meant to ask?

.@NoahSchweber Is this what you meant to ask?-yes.

@NoahSchweber would give me some idea how to reduce $\text{3SAT}\leq_p \text{GI}$?

@Beduin No, because that's not the way the reduction goes. GI reduces to 3SAT (this is what "3SAT is NP-complete" does for us here). So if GI is known to not be in P (which would follow from the optimality of any particular existing algorithm) then a fortiori 3SAT must not be in P.

Since $3\mathsf{SAT}$ is NP-complete, $\mathsf{GI}\le_p3\mathsf{SAT}$. That is to say, if the existing non-polynomial-time algorithm for $\mathsf{GI}$ is optimal, then a fortiori $3\mathsf{SAT}$ is not polytime-solvable.
But, of course, we have no idea whether the existing algorithm for $\mathsf{GI}$ is in fact optimal, so this isn't really saying anything useful.

If GI is NPH then $\text{3SAT}\leq_p \text{GI}$ possible?

@Beduin Notice that NP + NP-hard is the same as NP-complete. If GI is NP-complete, then by definition 3SAT reduces to GI.
